# laravel remover index.php de la url

Tags: laravel, url, reescritura-url

tengo un site donde puedo acceder con

```
https://www.pagina.com
```

pero también con

```
https://www.pagina.com/index.php
```

quisiera **NO** poder acceder con ese index.php (cuestiones de seo)

mi .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías prohibir el acceso, generando un `403 Forbidden`:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [NC,F]
```

O podrías redireccionar a `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```

- > No obstante, esta última te conviene unirla con la primer regla en tu .htaccess, para que redireccione 1 sola vez si termina con una barra al final, o si termina con `index.php`, aplicándolo así a cualquier `index.php` de cualquier carpeta (no solo del root).
  >
  > ```
  > # Redirect Trailing Slashes (and index.php) If Not A Folder...
  > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  > RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:(?:^|/)index\.php)?/$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
  > ```